# Select and Update Query MSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table named `BOOK`

I need a query that will discount the price of books by 10%, list the Book Code(PK),the Book Title and Discounted Price of each book.

I need to then change the price column to 'Discounted Price' as the name for the computed column.

I currently have

```
UPDATE BOOK SET PRICE = PRICE*0.9
SELECT CONCAT(PRICE) AS Discounted_Price,BOOK_CODE, BOOK_TITLE;
```

But I am getting an error message.

Comment: What is the error you got ?

Comment: What have you got so far in terms of code? What is the structure of your table? Look up the syntax for `alter table ... change`.

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT CONCAT(PRICE) AS Discounted_Price,BOOK_CODE, BOOK_TITLE' at line 2

Comment: I have my BOOK table all the fields I am trying to use match the names on my table

Comment: "I need a query that will discount the price of books by 10%, list the Book Code(PK),the Book Title and Discounted Price of each book. ". That's a description of _two_ queries. First the update, and then the select. Two separate operations.

Comment: what do you mean with the select condition  .,.after  the update? .. you want see the resulting set? ... or you need  some where condition for filter the row for updated? explain better

Comment: I am trying to discount the 'Price' field by 10% and then list the book  code, the title, and the price, however the column named Price has to be changed to 'discounted_price'

Comment: well what you've got is probably ok for that, but understand that it's not one query, it's two. So putting it all into one line of code will not work, as you've seen.

Comment: if you want all the rows to be updated ... just execute the update  .. (without select)  ..

Comment: @ADyson so there have to be two queries? I cannot make one?

Comment: No. An UPDATE is one type of query. It does an operation but returns no result. If you want to see the new state of the data after you've run the UPDATE operation, then you need to execute a separate SELECT statement, which is a different type of query. That's how SQL works. This won't cause you any kind of problem, it's fine to run multiple statements sequentially to do what you need to.

Comment: Alright thank you they work separately was just trying to see if I could make them one query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of updating the price in the table and avoiding to have two queries, you can have the desired result by a `SELECT` query like below :

```
Select BOOK_CODE, BOOK_TITLE, (PRICE * 0.9) as Discounted_Price from BOOK;
```

Comment: It's great that your problem is sorted out :)

Comment: Worth pointing out that this doesn't actually permanently update the price in the table, it just displays it 10% less, but that value is never stored anywhere. So it depends on the actual underlying requirement as to whether this is a suitable solution.

Answer (score 1):

please try the query below:

`UPDATE BOOK set PRICE = (PRICE * 0.9); Select PRICE as Discounter_Price, BOOK_CODE,BOOK_TITLE from BOOK;`

Comment: Yeah basically what I have now two queries, thank you though

Comment: If you dont want to have two queries, you can do it without updating the price field. Select (PRICE * 0.9) as Discounted_price, price as original_price, book_code, book_title from book;